# Pivot table based on the first value of the group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Have the following `DataFrame`:

[image]

I'm trying to pivot it in `pandas` and achieve the following format:

[image]

Actually I tried the classical approach with `pd.pivot_table()` but it does not work out:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,values='col2', index=[df.index], columns = 'col1')
```

Would be appreciate for some suggestions :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot` and then `dropna` for each column:

```
>>> df.pivot(columns='col1', values='col2').apply(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist()).astype(int)
col1  a  b  c
0     1  2  9
1     4  5  0
2     6  8  7
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a Series of lists using `groupby.agg`; then construct a DataFrame:

```py
out = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(list).pipe(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(zip(*x), columns=x.index.tolist()))
```

Output:

```py
   A  B  C
0  1  2  9
1  4  5  0
2  6  8  7
```